# Proper way to change contents of a VCL component

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

Quite often when I make VCL programs, I run into a scenario like this:

- I have a number of components on the form, that the users are allowed to fiddle with. Most commonly a bunch of edit boxes.
- The contents of these edit boxes need to be verified by the OnChange event when the user types in stuff manually.
- Somewhere else on the form, there's some component that the user can click on to get some default values loaded into the edit boxes (in TEdit::Text).

Now what I want is that whenever the user is typing something in the TEdit::Text, the OnChange event must process the user input. But when my program is setting the TEdit::Text to a default value, this isn't necessary, because then I know that the value is correct.

Unfortunately, writing code like `myedit->Text = "Default";` triggers the OnChange event.

I tend to solve this with what I think is a rather ugly approach: by creating a bool variable `is_user_input`, which `TEdit::OnChange` checks. If it is true, the TEdit::Text will get validated, otherwise it will get ignored. But of course, this doesn't prevent the program from launching `TEdit::OnChange` when it is unnecessary.

Is there a better or cleaner way to achieve this?

Is there a way for OnChange to check who called it? Or I suppose, a way of disabling the OnChange event temporarily would be even better. `TEdit::Enabled` doesn't seem to affect whether `OnChange` gets triggered or not.

Comment: Don't you consider it good that the verification is applied on your default values as well? What if you decide to change a default value at some point, and by mistake set it outside the legal range?

Comment: @barakmanos Normally, yes. But often there is a scenario where multiple components are related to the same set of private variables. So I let all of the components call the same "change" setter function from their individual OnChange. Now suppose I also want to change this variable internally - then I must update all components to reflect the change. And if I do, they automatically trigger their OnChange and launch the "change" function, over and over. So with such a design, I end up with weird, circular dependencies. Plus pointless execution delays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply unassign the `OnChange` event handler temporarily:

```
template <typename T>
void SetControlTextNoChange(T *Control, const String &S)
{
    TNotifyEvent event = Control->OnChange;
    Control->OnChange = NULL;
    try {
        Control->Text = S;
    }
    __finally {
        Control->OnChange = event;
    }
 }
```

```
SetControlTextNoChange(myedit, "Default");
```

Alternatively, RAII is good for this kind of thing:

```
template <typename T>
class DisableChangeEvent
{
private:
    T *m_control;
    TNotifyEvent m_event;
public:
    DisableChangeEvent(T *control);
    {
        m_control = control;
        m_event = control->OnChange;
        control->OnChange = NULL;
     }

    ~DisableChangeEvent();
    {
        m_control->OnChange = m_event;
    }

    T* operator->() { return m_control; }
};
```

```
DisableChangeEvent(myedit)->Text = "Default";
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good stuff. I'm assuming the RAII version would be called as `DisasbleChangeEvent<TEdit>(myedit)->Text = "Default";`?

Comment: Also, is `__finally` a C++ Builder extension or is that C++11 or something?

Comment: I omitted the `<TEdit>` portion because the compiler should be able to infer its value based on the parameter passed, but yes, you can also specify it explicitly.  And `__finally` is a C++Builder compiler extension.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for OnChange to check who called it?

Usually the events have a parameter Sender, you can check if(Sender ==ButtonSetDefaults) in the event function. Not sure what really happens if the Button triggers an OnChange event and have no way to test it now.

Otherwise I see no problem with a global variable except timing issues, but you can run into those with disabling events as well.

Comment: Yeah but who will be the sender when I type `myedit->Text = "hello";` somewhere in my program and OnChange triggers? Won't it always be its parent form who is the sender then? How can I use that to know whether it was the user or the program that triggered the function?

Comment: That's what I mean with not sure because I don't have a running Borland here, but maybe you can try it. When disabling the event you could run into problems when the another event fires while control->OnChange = NULL; Using a mutex might help then.

Comment: I made an experiment and it does indeed seem that `Sender` is always the edit box. Also I don't believe you can get the kind of problems you describe because all events in the GUI are normally executed from a single thread. IIrc, you may however run into similar issues, but they are then related to the Windows message queue. Something like... if you do something that causes a SendMessage rather than a PostMessage, you might get an event triggered while another is still running. I don't remember the details of how this works internally in Builder.

Comment: Okay, unless there is a function SetText(Sender,UncideString) I don't see a way to talk my way out of this one. Thx for trying and sorry for the wasted time!